# Enforcing a specific order for cookie headers

Tags: apache, cookies, apache2, http-headers, url-rewriting

We have an application that cares about the order of cookie headers. It shouldn't, since this isn't mandated by the standards and indeed we're getting the headers in various different orders

So we would like to rewrite the headers in Apache so that the cookie headers always appear in a specific order. Is there any way of doing this?

An ideal solution would be specifically about cookie headers, but something that lets us mess with the header order more generally would do too.

Comment: Is putting a reverse proxy in between an option? There must be some out there that can rewrite headers on the fly.

Comment: Apache is a reverse proxy in the solution - I'm not aware of anything else that can do this sort of header rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of writing your own apache module, I don't think this can be done. There's mod_headers which will let you add/modify existing headers, but I don't think it provides the functionality to do what you want.

You may want to ask this question on serverfault as well, you may have better luck there.

Comment: Thanks. Mod_headers looked at first that it might do it - but we need to match on the header value not its name (which is always set-cookie, of course) and even then it might not be possible